# Need clarity in "testng.xml" file

Tags: xml, testng, doctype

"`<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >`"

What does this particular line do while writing "testng.xml"?

I searched in Google and could not get any particular info. I even checked [the official testNG site](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml) but no use.

Answer (score 1):

It's related to structure of any xml file, it's called [external dtd declaration](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_intro.asp).

Comment: Not all XML files start from this particular line, so there is something specialty for this in TestNG framerwork i hope.

Comment: So true. More details then: xml document can be well-formed or restricted (validated) by a schema. Document Type Definition (DTD) is a provider of such schema. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Well-formedness_and_error-handling should give you some basic information on this matter. So, there is a DTD schema created especially for testng suite files, and each suite file, being a valid xml file should reference this schema (provided externally), what it duly does.